# How to deploy storm-cluster(storm 0.9.2 version) in Amazon EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-storm, ec2-ami

Can anybody tell me how to deploy A Storm Cluster On AWS EC2.
I have tired few links but they doesnt seems like working fine.
My storm version is 0.9.2, Is this version compatible with AWS EC2 or should i go to a lower version than 0.9.2.
Also need the links which can help me in the deploying of the storm cluster.
I have already tried the links https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-deploy but it didnt worked for me.

Comment: Are you getting a specific error that you can add to your question? Just create your topology packaged in the uber-jar, upload it to the server, and run `storm jar your-topology.jar YourTopology`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storm deploy project is old, maybe with new releases doesn't work fine. Have you tried [ubuntu-juju](https://juju.ubuntu.com/) which automate your cloud deployment. Juju have 'charms' that encapsulates configuration, deployment scripts to cloud enviroments...

Graphically you can set up you storm cluster. Below show a link to storm charm. It worked for me.

https://jujucharms.com/~maarten-ectors/precise/storm-5